# Why does Scala's withDefaultValue method return an unspecific Map?

Tags: scala, hashmap

`scala.collection.mutable.HashMap` inherits the `withDefaultValue` method in such a way that it returns a `Map`, not a `HashMap`.  Why is that?  I thought the Scala type system was clever enough to infer the type in such situations.  (Analogously, `x.map(y => ...)` returns a collection of the same type as `x`, using the aforementioned cleverness.)

I can work around the problem by writing `new HashMap[_S, T_] { override def default(x: _S_) = _d_ }`, but that yields a subclass of `HashMap`, which might cause problems in other contexts.

Perhaps someone can talk me into believing that `Map` is a better type than `HashMap` because it's more abstract.  I assume a `scala.collection.mutable.Map` is in fact implemented as a `HashMap`, but how can I be sure?

Answer (score 2):

Because the returned map is *not* a `HashMap`. It is a `scala.collection.immutable.Map.WithDefault`, a private class defined inside `scala.collection.immutable.Map`, and which does not inherit `HashMap`.

See [the source code of `WithDefault`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L86-L93) and [the implementation of `withDefaultValue`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Map.scala#L64).

Comment: In the question, it's `mutable`, not `immutable`.

Comment: It doesn't matter. The same applies to mutable maps: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.4/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/Map.scala#L86-L93

Comment: I mean that the returned map is `scala.collection.mutable.Map.WithDefault`, not `scala.collection.immutable.Map.WithDefault`.